# What is a JetpackCompose equivalent for Flutter Wrap widget?

Tags: flutter, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to have row which automatically goes in next line after it fits current line.

Comment: flutter wrap: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this address:

**[Flow Layout]** https://google.github.io/accompanist/flowlayout/.

This layout resembles the Wrap widget in Flutter.

- FlowRow
- FlowColumn

---

```
FlowRow {
    list?.forEach { item ->
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(
                vertical = 4.dp,
                horizontal = 8.dp
            ),
            text = item.name ?: "Unknown"
        )
    }
}
```